# Почему не загружается картинка через ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){  
           e.preventDefault();  
           if($('#image_file').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Please Select the File");  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>userlk/ajax_upload",   
                     //base_url() = http://localhost/tutorial/codeigniter  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:new FormData(this),
                     contentType: false,
                     cache: false,
                     processData:false,
                     success:function(data)
                     {  
                          $('#uploaded_image').html(data);  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
 });
```

```html
<div class="container">  
 <br /><br /><br />  
 <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>  
 <form method="post" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
     <input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" />  
     <br />  
     <br />  
     <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload" />
 </form>  
 <br />  
 <br />  
 <div id="uploaded_image">  
 </div>
</div>
```

```
function image_upload() {

        $this->data['title'] = "Upload image";

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('userlk/image_upload', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }

    function ajax_upload() {
        if(isset($_FILES["image_file"]["name"])) {
            $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
            $this->load->library('upload');
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image_file')) {
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }
            else {
                $this->data = $this->upload->data();
                echo '<img src="'.base_url().'upload/'.$this->data["file_name"].'" width="300" height="225" class="img-thumbnail" />';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `contentType: false,` - это что значит?

Comment: contentType: false, чтобы jquery не устанавливал contentType